# Margin collapsing in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Typically, in CSS, when a parent and its last child have a margin, the margins collapse to create a single margin. E.g.

```css
article {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

main {
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <main>
    <article>
      Item 1
    </article>
    <article>
      Item 2
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

As you can see, even though a margin of `20px` is specified on both the `article` and the `main` tags, you only get a `20px` margin between the last *article* and *footer*.

When using *flexbox*, however, we get a `40px` margin between the last *article* and *footer* — a full `20p`x margin from the article to main, and another `20px` from main to *footer*.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

main {
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <main>
    <article>
      Item 1
    </article>
    <article>
      Item 2
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make *flexbox* margins behave the same way as the non-flexbox ones?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Margin collapsing is a feature of a [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins).

There is no margin collapsing in a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` `display`
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. For example,
>   floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the flex
>   container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.

Comment: nnnnnooooooooooooooo don't tell me this! how do I get rid of my extra space between modules?

Comment: @TomRoggero maybe add a wrapper for that content to work in block formatting context? The wrapper then exists in a flex formatting context, but not its content — I would guess. However, wrapping tends to breaks good, nice, semantic markup.

Comment: It's so annoying we don't have a way to toggle margin collapse on/off as we see fit

Comment: To clarify something that wasn't clear to me: It's the *flex items* (rather than the *flex container* itself) that don't get collapsing margins. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/tup8nxqo/ You will notice that the flex items A, B, C have a 50px margin each, but are 100px apart. The two flex containers have 100px margin each, and those margins collapse.

Comment: @HenrikN, just to be clear -- because you mentioned the relative margins of A, B and C -- margin collapsing only applies to vertical margins. [Horizontal margins never collapse.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Thank you, @Michael_B! Good catch. This is an updated example that uses `flex-direction: column`: https://jsfiddle.net/9qenzs2L/ As with the first example, the adjacent flex items don't have their (now vertical) margins collapse.

Comment: Why do all good things must come with some flaw ?

Comment: In practice, if you want margin collapse -like effect, you have to use margin for the flex *container* and `gap` for the flex items. Unfortunately, with `gap` you can only set one value for both horizontal and vertical directions so it's much less flexible (pun intented) than true margin collapse. Also note that the visitors will need pretty recent version of Safari because Apple took forever to support `gap` and without support for it, the actual rendering will look like you had set `gap:0` everywhere.

Comment: so ... it is true. even in 2023 we cannot have a normal simple way to vertically align something without breaking something else lol. what a time to be alive

Answer (score 25):

though margin collapse is not possible with flexbox, you can use `gap` to achieve the same result:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 5px;
    row-gap: 15px;
      
    max-width: 70px;
    outline: 1px solid #440;
}

.parent > div {
    background: #8ff;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Comment: No Safari support as of April 2021

Comment: Now in Safari (14.1+ as of April 25, 2021)
https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_row-gap_flex_context

Comment: If you use `gap`, you should be aware that it took ages for Apple to support this. If you have to support old (unsupported by Apple!) Apple devices, it may not safe to use `gap` even today. If you can get Apple users to install iOS 15 or greater, there will be no problems with `gap`.

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: This is not a way to make margins behave in a flex box layout the same way as they do in a block layout; however, this may help resolve the margin problem in some cases.

Instead of relying on collapsing margins, you can use pseudo selectors to get the effect you want:

```css
main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

article{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}

article:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer{
  background: #eef;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    This is article number 1
  </article>
  <article>
    This is article number 2
  </article>
  <article>
    This is article number 3
  </article>
</main>
<footer>
  This is the footer of the page
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

`margin-trim` is likely to be added to the css specifications, which will deal with these type of situations. More details are found in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-trim. Browser support can be viewed here: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_margin-trim

Comment: Two years later `margin-trip` is still implemented in zero browsers so I wouldn't expect this to happen anytime soon. Also note that `margin-trip` would be different feature from hypothetical `margin-collapse` which is the feature asked in the question. The `margin-trim` is about setting logical margin value to zero for some edge cases whereas `margin-collapse` would be overlapping margin areas.

Comment: Now supported in Safari (but nowhere else yet)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains why it doesn't work, but does not provide a solution. Here's a way to make the flexbox elements align just like the non-flexbox example.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

main > article + article {
  margin-top: 20px
}

footer {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <main>
    <article>
      Item 1
    </article>
    <article>
      Item 2
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: this wouldn't work well with wrapped elements though

Comment: You probably should use the `gap` property if you want space between the items within the flexbox. I still think it would awesome to be able to toggle margin-collapse on and off at will but this is not supported for flex items.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen you are correct. That said, browser support for `gap` was not the same in 2020. Stack Overflow answers should always be read in the context of their post date.

Comment: I think the intent of the Stack Overflow is to update the answers in the long run, or at least allow comments that explain the current situation. The Edit and Comment features do not get disabled even for old content unlike e.g. Reddit – and this is exactly to allow fixing historical answers.