# How to eliminate the space under the content?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a conainer element, which is at least the height of the page. I set it like this: `min-height: 100vh`

The body has no margin.

For some reason, an empty space appears under the element. How is it possible to eliminate that?

I can observe this error in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox.

My code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: chrome]

Comment: add some padding on container (1px) , for some reasons, margin-bottom on item jumps outside the container  https://jsfiddle.net/z8tg1746/ or remove the margin on the last item https://jsfiddle.net/ahm9yqoL/

Comment: The reason you're seeing that is because of the height 100 percent, the 100 percent does not always work as expected , you will have to use either JavaScript for your height, or a combination of display type flex for the height

Comment: about margins jumping out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing  **Parent and first/last child**
    *`If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.`*

Comment: @G-Cyr yet another strange case of margin collapsing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48777787/8620333

Comment: The duplicate question is more generic than this one. The answer explain why both FF and Chrome behave differently and you will also find the relevant part of the specification to describe all this

Comment: @TemaniAfif i think it's a small bug since it happens not in every browsers and caring about margin collapsing cures it. Agreed that it should not happen before the margin value is bigger than the space left in the parent. For me it is an unexpeted behavior that is easily taken care of. nothing to compare of what MSIE 6 use to be ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr it's not really a bug because it's defined in the spec (`bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height`) and FF is somehow violating that spec (like Bolt is explaining in my question) but yes it's counter intuive and should probably change.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work by removing the margin of the last `.item` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100px;
}
.item:last-child { 
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The margin is not the issue , but rather the extra space that is left after the margin

Comment: @ImmortalDude, agreed! Your solution of using the flexbox is the correct approach.

Comment: @ImmortalDude the margin seems to be the BUG https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing .. agreed it should not happen here, but it does and removing it cures the issue

Comment: @G-Cyr a simple reset applied to the html and body elements also fixes the issue, no need to remove the margin from the element

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the `.container` margin to center with `auto` and the `.item` children having a bottom margin. For some reason the causing a lack of collapse which is, in turn, causing the margin to overflow (or append to) it's owner, even if `margin-bottom: 0` is applied to `.container`.

To resolve this, we have come up with a different way, by not using `margin: auto;`, of centering the `.container`.

As well as, to force a collapse by setting a height relationship between culprit of the overflow and it's parent. We will accomplish this by setting `height: 100%;` to `html, body`.

I will propose three solutions which solve the display discrepancy.

**Option 1**

*Edit: This solution does not seem to be consistent to me in Edge upon further testing. Sometimes I have to open DevTools and toggle `min-height: 100vh;` in `.container` to get it to render correctly.*

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  /* Remove the margin */
  /* margin: auto; */
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This fixes the issue in Edge and Chrome. To answer the question, this is the only edit required.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qoxnuhv/1/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

.item {  
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

---

**Option 2**

This method is a slight modification to how the `.item` `margin` is applied where we will apply to all `.item`'s except the last one using `:not(last-child)`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qoxnuhv/2/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

.item {  
  position: relative;      
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

---

**Option 3**

If you're familiar with Flexbox, you could solve it that way with the following edits to your CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  /* Without a min height set the width 
  /*   will default to the content's width */
  /* max-width: 200px; */
  width: 200px;
  
  margin: auto;
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {  
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here, we set `body` as flexbox, set as `column` direction, and center the content (direct children).

Importantly, we have to  set a minimum width so that if our content is less than `200px` it won't get squished.

Comment: did you checked it ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it.

Comment: so add a demo to your answer . https://jsfiddle.net/ahm9yqoL/1/ and eventually explanation ;) but keep min-height , it will be content going into that container ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr I updated my answer to show the sample html file I used to help determine an answer.

Comment: flex is not there , is it ? and body is still up to 100% . do you know why flex would work well ? . it is about   block formatting context triggered

Comment: No. I suggested flexbox, but I wasn't sure if OP is comfortable with it, so I found a less complicated method and went with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193420/discussion-between-seantunwin-and-g-cyr).

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `height: 100%` on the container for it to be the height of the page at all times.

Comment: That may not always give expected results

Answer (score 0):

The below modified code should help you. Set `margin: 0` in the `html` and `body` elements

```css
html, body { /* or use * to apply this margin reset to all elements */
  margin :0;
}

body{
  background: red;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  
  height:100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ?? container is supposed to be at the minimum  100vh height showing a background till the bottom. it does not anymore

Comment: @G-Cyr updated the answer as I misunderstood what was the issue

Comment: the op had already set margin:0 to body ,  he has this 1em extra outside the container in chrome and edge only, this should happen only when the last item reaches the bottom of the container. vertical margins are shown outside containers if no borders,padding or block formatting context is set . The problem here is that it happens even if there is more than 1em free space in the .container below the last item.

Comment: Not just body but also html, that is what removed the issue on my browsers "chrome 74", the op has not included the margin 0 to the html as well

Comment: okay, i did not expect this , funny

Comment: @G-Cyr, yeah , I didn't have this problem as I always apply margin, padding, border, outline, font-size resets to all my elements , didn't know that something like that existed, learned something from a question as opposed to an answer

Comment: hmmm, not working with my chrome https://jsfiddle.net/pmvy4q1t/  **Version 74.0.3729.131 (Build officiel) (64 bits)**

Comment: @G-Cyr, quite odd, it seems to work perfectly in mine

Comment: mysteries of the internet :)

Comment: @G-Cyr, I will get back to you, if I find anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193422/discussion-between-immortal-dude-and-g-cyr).

Answer (score -3):

You might try to add some padding to your .item

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all 1) does not contain any code 2) padding has got nothing to do with the issue, it the way height is interpreted but the browsers in question

Comment: padding has to do with collapsing margins. but agreed, this is not an answer , but a comment

Comment: Sorry I meant to comment not post an answer but thank you