# How works margin collapsing with min-height?

Tags: html, css, height, margin, specifications

I've read in the spec this:

[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a 'height' of 'auto' and a **'min-height' of zero** collapses with its last in-flow block-level child's bottom margin if the box has no bottom padding and no bottom border and the child's bottom margin does not collapse with a top margin that has clearance.

But as for min-height I can't say that the spec tells us the truth. Here's some example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*parent with min-height*/
.block {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: rgba(4, 127, 214, 1);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child_1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: yellow;
}

.child_2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="child_1"></div>
  <div class="child_2"></div>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

This example shows us that margins can collapsing with min-height. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That version of the Specification is probably a bit confusing. You can check the updated [version (2.2)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins) where the main rule is:

> both belong to **vertically-adjacent box edges**, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
> ...
>
> - bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent **has 'auto' computed height**

Then the rule you quoted will become:

> The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a 'height' of 'auto' collapses with its last in-flow block-level child's bottom margin, if:
>
> - the box has no bottom padding, and
> - the box has no bottom border, and
> - the child's bottom margin neither collapses with a top margin that has clearance, nor (if the box's min-height is non-zero) with the box's top margin.

The `min-height` is no longer there.

---

As a side note, the rule you quoted is an implication of the main rules listed above where there is nothing about `min-height` so having a margin collapsing in case of min-height different from auto won't be a surprise for me if it happens (even if it's non intuitive).

**UPDATE**

A related old question [Margin collapsing with floated element, why there is an extra margin added?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48777787/8620333). It's now an irrelevant one since we cannot reproduce the behavior but margin-collapsing was occuring in all the cases even if the `min-height` was bigger than the childs height.

---

I guess the *vertically-adjacent box edges* is the key to understand what is happening. If a `min-height` make both elements no more adjacent then no margin collapsing will occur (which is logical), otherwise you will have margin collapsing (like in your example).