# How to use margin collapse with flexbox in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

In example below I'm trying to use margin collapse with bootstrap 4 and I expect 50px gap between button and column, but it is 100px by `display: flex;` set on the `.row`. How can I achieve margin collapse here?

```css
.test-block {
  background: #FFDC00;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.test-element.col-12 {
  background: #FF4136;
}

.button-block {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.btn-caption {
  color: #111;
}

* {
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Bootstrap 4</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 button-block">
    <a class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
    <div class="btn-caption">Caption</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>No Bootstrap</h1>
  <div class="test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="test-block">
    test block
  </div>
  <div class="button-block">
    <a class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
    <div class="btn-caption">Caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882869/margin-collapsing-in-flexbox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Hope this can be of some help.

Comment: first tou need to add container before row

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree, but this doesnt change the behavior

Comment: i know, but simply to make your code more correct

Comment: by the way why you don't simply remove the extra margin ? why searching for margin-collapsin when people want to avoid it