# CSS Flexbox - Center all child elements with full height relative to the parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to align all child elements with full height relative to the parent element.

Everything is fine until I use the **align-items: center;** property, I align the elements but it does not cover 100%, and if I use **align-self: stretch;** covers 100% but does not align the elements vertically, there is some solution for this.

```css
.abouts {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.abouts .item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="abouts">
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content height...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content for test equal height all elements more content for test equal height all elements...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
</div>
```

Comment: The explanation of the problem and various solutions are provided in the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the `.abouts` flex parent use `align-items: stretch` to make the `.item` children take on their parent's height. Then (you could) make the `.item` children into flex parents themselves. You'll then have to adjust your text margins ([because there is no margin collapse in flex formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43882888/5796134))

```
.abouts .item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.abouts {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.abouts .item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="abouts">
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content height...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->

  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->

  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content for test equal height all elements more content for test equal height all elements...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Much of my understanding of the flex model comes from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/… it's a **really good** breakdown of all the properties.