# How can I make margin behave the same in a flex container and out of it?

Tags: html, css, margin

I got a problem. when using margin inside a flexbox it have double the size of what it should be (like it doesnt collide or so)

This is where I have the problem:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y45ebuxa/)
This is the code:

```
<div style="height: 350px;">
<div style="height: 182px; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; flex-direction: column;">
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 94.5px; width: 80px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 94.5px; width: 80px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 87.5px; width: 80px; background-color: brown;"></div>
</div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 31.5px; width: 80px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 31.5px; width: 80px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 52.5px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px; height: 52.5px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

What is the reason for this? And how can I make the margin behave the same on both flex container and out of it?

Comment: short answer: you cannot. You are facing margin collapsing and this *feature* is disabled in a flexbox context. Either disable margin collpasing outside (use inline-bock for example) or change the margin to they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not doubling the size inside the flexbox. In flexbox, the margin is considered of upper `div` as well as lower `div`

```
i.e. total margin = upper div margin + lower div margin
```

but outside of the flexbox, the margin is considered as the

```
max (upper div margin, lower div margin ).
```

This phenomenon is called **Margin Collapse**.

[Margin Collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

***Top and bottom margins of elements are sometimes collapsed into a single margin that is equal to the largest of the two margins.
This does not happen on the left and right margins! Only the top and bottom margins!***

Comment: Thanks to your answer I stopped trying to fix what have and change it. posted an solution I came to.

Answer (score 3):

**Why does it behave this way?**
Margin collapsing works in [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins) and not in [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43882888/4825498) is [@Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b)'s answer explaining the reason behind this.

**How do I get collapsible margin?**
One way is to wrap the 3 div blocks with a div. There could be a better way, but you can try and share here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I learned a lot!

The simple solution I came to is using:
margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;

I don't know why I didn't came up with this earlier.

You can see it works now [here](https://jsfiddle.net/idocoh/y45ebuxa/12/)

```
<div style="height: 350px;">
<div style="height: 182px; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; flex-direction: column;">
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 94.5px; width: 80px; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 94.5px; width: 80px; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 87.5px; width: 80px; background-color: brown; display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 31.5px; width: 80px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 31.5px; width: 80px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 52.5px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; height: 52.5px; width: 80px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```