# Why don't inline-flex containers' margins collapse?

Tags: css, margin, display

I understand that items *within* a flex container obey different rules for margin collapsing than they normally would (i.e. when not within a flex wrapper). However, the *container itself*'s margins should still behave normally, right? In other words, why are the margins different in the two containers in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/msoltvedt/pen/XWpgYmE)?

[border collapse example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLH30.png)

```css
h1, h2 {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.inline-flexed,
.flexed {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-flexed {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flexed {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<h1>I have margins!</h1>

<span class="inline-flexed">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="right">My container is inline-flex'ed. For some reason my parent's container's margins don't collapse.</span>
</span>

<h2>I also have margins!</h2>

<span class="flexed">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="right">My container is flex'ed. My parent's container's margins collapse as you'd expect.</span>
</span>

<h2>Is this a browser bug?</h2>
```

Comment: `inline-*` element aren't a part of the margin collapsing rules: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins (only block level elements are) --> *Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).*

Answer (score 2):

`inline-flex` generates a **flex** container that is **inline-level** element. Margin of **inline-*** elements does not collapse.

---

It is documented here.

> #### Inline-flex
>
> This value causes an element to generate a flex container box that is **inline-level** when placed in flow layout. [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)

> #### Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - *Both belong to **in-flow block-level** boxes that participate in the same block formatting context.*
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them (Note that certain zero-height line boxes (see 9.4.2) are ignored for this purpose.)
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges. [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

### Similar question

[Margin collapsing in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882869/margin-collapsing-in-flexbox)

#### More info

https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/margins-in-css/